# how to cut data in excel using formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

i use ms excel 2007

i want to cut a row in sheet 1 then paste it to sheet 2 using a formula in excel
i have already used =VLOOKUP or =A1 but it is only copy the data and not CUT it

thanks for all your help

Comment: You CAN NOT do it. Formulas can only display information in the current cell, but they can't influence other cells in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a formula, but more than capable of doing it in VBA. Soemthing along the lines of:

```
Sub cut()

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change your sheet names if they are different
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
sh1.Range("A1:H1").cut sh2.Range("A1:H1") 'Select the range you are cutting from and where it being pasted

End Sub
```

You could also use .EntireRow if its the full row you are cutting.

```
Sub cut()

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change your sheet names if they are different
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
sh1.Range("A1").EntireRow.cut sh2.Range("A1")


End Sub
```

Check out this [link](https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/range/m/cut/) on how to use the .cut method.